# about route table setting, and ssh between vmware

Tags: networking, ssh, vmware, route

I have 2 physical machines: a PC and a notebook.

1. under PC(WIN7, 192.168.1.2) have a VMWARE, VMWARE installed one Solaris (172.168.1.50). I can use putty to access Solaris from the PC.
2. notebook (WIN7, 192.168.1.3), I can't use putty to access Solaris from  the notebook.

My question is how: to access Solaris from the notebook?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are using `internal networking` for the Virtual Machine. If you can change the adapter in VMWare to `bridged mode` instead, your Solaris machine will be on the same network/subnet as your PC and laptop.

If that is not an option, then you need to:

1. In the laptop, set the router/gateway to the IP address of your PC with VMWare.
2. You might also need to enable IP routing on the PC running VMWare (assuming VMWare Workstaion or Player)

To do this in Windows, run regedit and browse to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\ Services\Tcpip\Parameters\IPEnableRouter` and set the value to `1`

To do this in Linux, from a console run `sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`

Comment: Thanks Tim, i want to know more from you, what do you think to do route add?

route add 172.168.1.50 MASK 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.2, use this route on notebook, right?

Comment: That would also suffice, but you need to enable "IP Forwarding" on 192.168.1.2 :)